# Android set image view height according to width

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview

How can I set ImageView's height to keep it's aspect ratio? In XML I set fill_parent as layout width and wrap_content as layout height, but I got this:
[Screenshot http://kepfeltoltes.hu/141206/Screenshot_2014-12-06-19-09-30_1__www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/141206/Screenshot_2014-12-06-19-09-30_1__www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in XML or `setAdjustViewBounds(true)` in code on your ImageView

Comment: It works, thank you :) ... I was thinking on this when I realised that I formulated this question very stupidly. I came back to correct it but I'm glad to see that you managed to found out what I mean...